# AbstractMethodError with jTDS JDBC Driver on Tomcat 8

Tags: tomcat8, jtds

I am deploying a web app (WAR) to a Tomcat 8 web container.

The WAR includes in the '/WEB-INF/lib' directory the following jTDS JDBC driver:

```
<dependency org="net.sourceforge.jtds" name="jtds" rev="1.3.1" />
```

(file is: `jtds-1.3.1.jar`).

This is how the resource is defined in `META-INF/context.xml`:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/jtds/sybase/somedb"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          driverClassName="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
          url="jdbc:jtds:sybase://localhost:2501/somedb"
          username="someuser" password="somepassword"
/>
```

In my code I obtain the [javax.sql.DataSource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html) the normal way:

```
InitialContext cxt = new InitialContext();
if ( cxt == null ) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Uh oh -- no context!");
}
DataSource ds = (DataSource) cxt.lookup( lookupName );
```

I further verify (by printing) that the DataSource object `ds` is of the expected type:

```
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource
```

… but when I try to get a connection out of it:

```
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
```

… I get the following trace:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.isValid(JtdsConnection.java:2833)
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.isValid(DelegatingConnection.java:924)
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolableConnection.validate(PoolableConnection.java:282)
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.validateConnection(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:359)
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2316)
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2299)
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2043)
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1543)
```

What gives?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Turns out I had to add:

```
validationQuery="select 1"
```

in the Resource declaration in `context.xml`.

This is mentioned [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/jtds/bugs/750/) (although mispelled as `validateQuery`).

Digging into the implementation of `JtdsConnection` one sees:

```
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.sql.Connection#isValid(int)
 */
public boolean isValid(int timeout) throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    throw new AbstractMethodError();
}
```

This is really weird, I think [AbstractMethodError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AbstractMethodError.html)  is supposedly thrown by the compiler only, unimplemented methods ought to throw [UnsupportedOperationException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html). At any rate, the following code from [PoolableConnection](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-dbcp/8.0.24/org/apache/tomcat/dbcp/dbcp2/PoolableConnection.java?av=f) shows why the presence or not of `validationQuery` in `context.xml` can change things. Your `validationQuery` is passed as the value of the `sql` `String` parameter in the below method (or `null` if you don't define a `validationQuery`):

```
public void More ...validate(String sql, int timeout) throws SQLException {
    ...
    if (sql == null || sql.length() == 0) {
        ...
        if (!isValid(timeout)) {
            throw new SQLException("isValid() returned false");
        }
        return;
    }
...
}
```

So basically if no `validationQuery` is present, then the connection's own implementation of `isValid` is consulted which in the case of `JtdsConnection` weirdly throws `AbstractMethodError`.

Comment: I can run the app on Tomcat 7/Windows, driver 1.2.8 without a problem. I ran into this error when I migrated the app to a Docker/Linux environment. Adding the `validationQuery` to the driver's conf solved the problem.

Answer (score 7):

The answer mentioned above by Marcus worked for me when I encountered this problem. To give a specific example of how the validationQuery setting looks in the context.xml file:

```
    <Resource name="jdbc/myDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            driverClassName="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://SQLSERVER01:1433/mydbname;instance=MYDBINSTANCE"
            username="dbuserid" password="dbpassword"
            validationQuery="select 1"
            />
```

The validationQuery setting goes in with each driver setting for your db connections. So each time you add another db entry to your context.xml file, you will need to include this setting with the driver settings.

Answer (score 3):

The above answer works. If you are setting it up for standalone Java application, set the validation query in the datasource.

```
 BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource(); 

 ds.setUsername(user);
 ds.setPassword(getPassword());
 ds.setUrl(jdbcUrl);
 ds.setDriverClassName(driver);
 ds.setMaxTotal(10);
 ds.setValidationQuery("select 1"); //DBCP throws error without this query
```