# NiFi connection to SqlServor for ExecuteSQL

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, apache-nifi

I'm trying to import some data from different SqlServer databases using ExecuteSQL in NiFi, but it's returning me an error. I've already imported a lot of other tables from MySQL databases without any problem and I'm trying to use the same workflow structure for the SqlServer dbs.

The structure is as follows:

- There's a file `.txt` with the list of tables to be imported
- This file is fetched, splitted and uptaded; so there's a FlowFile for each table of each db that has to be imported,
- These FlowFiles are passed into ExecuteSQL which executes their contents

For example:

> file.txt
>
> `table1`
>   `table2`
>   `table3`

is being updated into 3 different FlowFiles:

> FlowFile1
>   `SELECT * FROM table1`
>
> FlowFile2
>   `SELECT * FROM table2`
>
> FlowFile3
>   `SELECT * FROM table3`

which are passed to ExecuteSQL.

Here follows the configuration of ExecuteSQL (identical for SqlServer tables and MySQL ones)

[ExecuteSQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZ5hZ.png)

---

As the only difference with the import from MySQL db is in the connectors, this is how a generic MySQL connector has been configured:

> SETTINGSPROPERTIES
>
> Database Connection URL `jdbc:mysql://00.00.00.00/DataBase?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&autoReconnect=true`
>   Database Driver Class Name `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`
>   Database Driver Location(s) `file:///path/mysql-connector-java-5.1.47-bin.jar`
>   Database User `user`
>   PasswordSensitive `value set`
>   Max Wait Time `500 millis`
>   Max Total Connections `8`
>   Validation query `No value set`

And this is how a SqlServer connector has been configured:

> SETTINGSPROPERTIES
>
> Database Connection URL `jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://00.00.00.00/DataBase;useNTLMv2=true;integratedSecurity=true;`
>   Database Driver Class Name `net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver`
>   Database Driver Location(s) `/path/connectors/jtds-1.3.1.jar`
>   Database User `user`
>   PasswordSensitive `value set`
>   Max Wait Time `-1`
>   Max Total Connections `8`
>   Validation query `No value set`

---

It has to be noticed that one (only one!) SqlServer connector works and the ExecuteSQL processor imports the data without any problem. The even stranger thing is that the database that is being connected via this connector is located in the same place as other two (the connection URL and user/psw are identical), but only the first one is working.

Notice that I've tried appending `?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&autoReconnect=true` also to the SqlServer connections, supposing it was a problem of date type, but it didn't give any positive change.

---

Here is the error that is being returned:

> 12:02:46 CEST ERROR f1553b83-a173-1c0f-93cb-1c32f0f46d1d
>   00.00.00.00:0000 ExecuteSQL[id=****]     ExecuteSQL[id=****] failed to process session due to null; Processor Administratively Yielded for 1 sec: java.lang.AbstractMethodError

---

Error retrieved from logs:

> ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-49] o.a.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteSQL ExecuteSQL[id=****] ExecuteSQL[id=****] failed to process session due to java.lang.AbstractMethodError; Processor Administratively Yielded for 1 sec: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
>   java.lang.AbstractMethodError: null
>       at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.isValid(JtdsConnection.java:2833)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.isValid(DelegatingConnection.java:874)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnection.validate(PoolableConnection.java:270)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.validateConnection(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:389)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2398)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2381)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2110)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1563)
>       at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool.getConnection(DBCPConnectionPool.java:305)
>       at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPService.getConnection(DBCPService.java:49)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1696.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.apache.nifi.controller.service.StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.java:84)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy449.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.AbstractExecuteSQL.onTrigger(AbstractExecuteSQL.java:195)
>       at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
>       at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1165)
>       at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:203)
>       at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: please provide the full stacktrace from the log file. there should be the cause of the problem.

Comment: try to set validation query to `select 1`. details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41231750/abstractmethoderror-with-jtds-jdbc-driver-on-tomcat-8

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I am stuck with the same error..